# scala: method declaration without a parameter

Tags: scala, methods, functional-programming, interop, scala-java-interop

i know that a function is not a method. I need a method (for interop with java) and i don't want to pass parameter because it can be inferred from the body. i'd like to do:

```
def upperCaseOrNull = StringUtils.stripToNull _ compose StringUtils.upperCase _
```

which is a perfect function String => String but it's not a method so in java i have to do

```
upperCaseOrNull().apply("a")
```

instead of simply:

```
upperCaseOrNull("a")
```

To make java happy i have to use unnecessary function wrapping

```
def upperCaseOrNull(string : String) = 
           (StringUtils.stripToNull _ compose StringUtils.upperCase _) (string)
```

which is usually considered as a bad style in functional programming. so can i somehow declare a method without passing unnecessary parameter?

Comment: Why not just `def upperCaseOrNull(string: String) = StringUtils.stripToNull(StringUtils.upperCase(string))`? I don't see any profit from function composition here.

Comment: you're absolutely right. there is no profit here. i just want to know if point-free style is available in scala-java interop

Comment: @chemikadze I think you should post that as an answer so the question can be closed

Comment: "i just want to know if point-free style is available in scala-java interop" No.